# How to Select Top 3 Highest Values From Each GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a Marks table where Student's Quiz Marks and Assignment marks are entered  in the following way

| StudentID | CourseID | Quiz1 | Quiz2 | Quiz3 | Quiz4 | Quiz5 | Assignment1 | Assignment2 | Assignment3 | Assignment4 | Assignment5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 321 | **10** | **8** | 4 | 1 | **9** | **7** | 3 | **9** | **8** | 5 |
| 2 | 321 | **6** | **10** | 6 | 3 | **8** | 4 | **7** | 1 | **8** | **6** |
| 3 | 321 | **7** | **9** | 2 | **8** | 4 | **10** | **7** | 5 | **8** | 3 |
| 4 | 321 | **7** | 2 | **6** | 4 | **8** | 3 | **6** | **9** | **10** | 5 |
| 5 | 321 | 3 | 4 | **5** | **7** | **10** | 5 | **7** | **8** | 3 | **9** |

Now I want to select the highest 3 quiz numbers and the highest 3 assignment numbers and sum them as the total quiz and total assignment numbers respectively for each student. I have bold highest numbers in the above table for a better understanding

The result should be something like this

| StudentID | CourseID | QuizTotal | AssignmentTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 321 | 27 | 24 |
| 2 | 321 | 24 | 21 |
| 3 | 321 | 24 | 25 |
| 4 | 321 | 21 | 25 |
| 5 | 321 | 22 | 24 |

What I have Tried is unpivot technique but the result is not what I am expecting. Here's what I tried

```
SELECT TOP(3) StudentID,  Marks 
FROM
(SELECT StudentID,CourseID , Quiz1, Quiz2, Quiz3, Quiz4, Quiz5  FROM Marks) stu

UNPIVOT

(Marks FOR QuizNo IN (Quiz1, Quiz, Quiz3, Quiz4, Quiz5)) AS mrks 


WHERE    (CourseID = 321)
Order by Marks Desc
```

Comment: You have a serious design problem.  You should a) store quiz and assignment results in separate tables, and b) store one quiz/assignment value per student in a single row.  I tried writing a query for this, but it was so ugly that I got discouraged and gave up.

Comment: ^^ as Tim said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to unpivot and sum marks with CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT StudentID, CourseID, qm.m, am.m
FROM Marks 
cross apply (
  select sum (q) m
  from (
     select top(3) q
     from (
       values
         (Quiz1),(Quiz2),(Quiz3),(Quiz4),(Quiz5)
       ) t(q)
     order by q desc
     ) tq
  ) qm
cross apply (
  select sum (q) m
  from (
     select top(3) q
     from (
       values
         (Assignment1),(Assignment2),(Assignment3),(Assignment4),(Assignment5)
       ) t(q)
     order by q desc
     ) tq
  ) am
```